# Having two divs on two different rows

Tags: asp.net, css

I have the following code. I basically want to have two rows, the first with a fileuploader on the left and a button on the right, and the next with a message, but the following code puts the label in my first row between the fileuploader and the button.

```
<style>
    .balUploader
    {
        margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;
        padding:0px 0px 0px 0px;
        width:80%;
        float:left;
    }
    .balUploaderCleaner
    {
        margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;
        padding:0px 0px 0px 0px;
        float:right;
    }
</style>

<div>
    <div>
        <asp:FileUpload ID="uploader" CssClass="balUploader" runat="server"/>
        <asp:ImageButton ID="uploaderEraser" CssClass="balUploaderCleaner" OnClick="uploaderEraser_Click" runat="server" Width="25" Height="25" />
    </div>
    <asp:Label ID="fileSizeError" runat="server" ForeColor="Red">bla bla bla bla bla bla</asp:Label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first `div` contains only floated elements, its height is calculated as 0, one of the ways to overcome that is to use a `clear`ing fix.

```
<style>
    .clearFix:before,
    .clearFix:after {
        content: " ";
        display: table;
        height: 0;
        clear: both;
        overflow: hidden;
        visibility: hidden;
    }
    .balUploader
    {
        margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;
        padding:0px 0px 0px 0px;
        width:80%;
        float:left;
    }
    .balUploaderCleaner
    {
        margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;
        padding:0px 0px 0px 0px;
        float:right;
    }
</style>

<div>
    <div class="clearFix">
        <asp:FileUpload ID="uploader" CssClass="balUploader" runat="server"/>
        <asp:ImageButton ID="uploaderEraser" CssClass="balUploaderCleaner" OnClick="uploaderEraser_Click" runat="server" Width="25" Height="25" />
    </div>
    <asp:Label ID="fileSizeError" runat="server" ForeColor="Red">bla bla bla bla bla bla</asp:Label>
</div>
```

Comment: desn't work for me. I copied and pasted the code above.

Comment: I managed to do it with the clear both by adding it to the label. Thanks.

Comment: @balauru You are welcome! Glad to be of help to you.

Comment: @balauru P.S. A self-sufficient clearing container that is not dependent on the following elements is a better solution, see the updated answer.